# VB.NET SQL Update not working

Tags: sql, vb.net

I have tried to get this SQL Update code to work for a couple days, and I can't do it, would anyone be able to help me?

```
    dbAccess.AddParameter("@flashcardID", flashcardUpdateIndex)
    dbAccess.AddParameter("@flashcardFront", txtFlashcardFront.Text)
    dbAccess.AddParameter("@flashcardBack", txtFlashcardBack.Text)

    dbAccess.ExecuteQuery("UPDATE Questions SET Flashcard_Front=@flashcardFront WHERE Question_ID=@flashcardID;")
```

Then this is the class dbAccess that I have created

```
Imports System.Data.OleDb

Public Class DBControl

'create database connection'
Private DBConnection As New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=Project_DB.mdb")

'create database command'
Private DBCommand As OleDbCommand

'storing data'
Public DBDA As OleDbDataAdapter
Public DBDT As DataTable

'query parameters'
Public parameters As New List(Of OleDbParameter)

'query stats'
Public recordcount As Integer
Public exception As String

Public Sub ExecuteQuery(Query As String)

    'reset query stats'
    recordcount = 0
    exception = ""

    'continue
    Try
        'open connection'
        DBConnection.Open()

        'create database command'
        DBCommand = New OleDbCommand(Query, DBConnection)

        'load parameters into database command'
        parameters.ForEach(Sub(p) DBCommand.Parameters.Add(p))

        'clear parameter list'
        parameters.Clear()

        'execute command and fill datatable'
        DBDT = New DataTable
        DBDA = New OleDbDataAdapter(DBCommand)
        recordcount = DBDA.Fill(DBDT)

    Catch ex As Exception
    End Try

    'close connection to database'
    If DBConnection.State = ConnectionState.Open Then
        DBConnection.Close()
    End If

End Sub

Public Sub AddParameter(name As String, value As Object)

    'include query and command parameters'
    Dim newParameter As New OleDbParameter(name, value)
    parameters.Add(newParameter)
End Sub

End Class
```

if anyone would be able to help that would be great! 
INSERT, DELETE, SELECT all work as expected, it is just UPDATE

Comment: you are blocking all the exceptions...how do you expect to figure out the problem with a blank exception handler...that "ex" has the information you need

Comment: *I can't do it* and *not working* are bad problem descriptions.  Perhaps if you were not eating any and all exceptions you might have something to go on.  Note that there are a number of issues with that dbAccess class - for instance an UPDATE query need not fill a DataTable.  You ought to focus on performing the DB Ops directly and then write the class *after* you know how they work, if you still think you need it.  Read [ask] and take the [tour]

Comment: It may be a bit too much to explain in a comment,i can't even post an answer to this :( .. But u can join me in [chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/168055/personal-chats) where i'll try to explain your issue as well as how to ask a proper qs here :)

Comment: why are you adding `@flashcardBack` parameter but not using it in the query?

Comment: planned to use @flashcardBack in another query, but as the first query does not work then I didn't write the second one. Also, how do I get the exception? The code itself does not crash so I am confused

Comment: You want to catch it in your UI or at least in your case in VS will tell you its unhandled.  The ex contains your information. Put this in your catch block since its a generic database class, later you can change it to an inherited exception class with more custom properties like the statement you are calling.  Throw new Exception("Database Error: " ex.Message, ex)

Comment: Underneath the line which  goes... "Catch ex As Exception" You should add "MsgBox(ex.Message)" This will popup a message box DESCRIBING the error. And hopefully help you pin down the cause of the error.

Comment: Add a couple of breakpoints to your code and check if the correct values are being passed around.

Comment: I added the MsgBox for the exception. When I run the code, no exception is thrown, but the UPDATE still does not complete. I added breakpoints too and all the correct values are being passed into the query, so I am unsure. Thanks

Comment: OleDB parameters have to be added in the order they appear in the sql statement.  That means front, then id, then remove back.

Answer (score 0):

As **Lars** mentioned above in the comments,
Your parameters have to be added in the same sequence as they do in your sql statment

```
dbAccess.AddParameter("@flashcardFront", txtFlashcardFront.Text)
dbAccess.AddParameter("@flashcardID", flashcardUpdateIndex)
' rem this line out for now - dbAccess.AddParameter("@flashcardBack", txtFlashcardBack.Text)

dbAccess.ExecuteQuery("UPDATE Questions SET Flashcard_Front=@flashcardFront WHERE Question_ID=@flashcardID;")
```

Aditionally, in your class code below you are declaring exception as string?
Change that line to

```
dim ex as exception
```

And move into the ExecuteQuery subroutine, that's where you use it and that's where it should live, that is **UNLESS** you want to access the exception info (if any) **OUTSIDE** that subroutine.

```
Imports System.Data.OleDb

Public Class DBControl

    'create database connection'
    Private DBConnection As New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=Project_DB.mdb")

    'create database command'
    Private DBCommand As OleDbCommand

    'storing data'
    Public DBDA As OleDbDataAdapter
    Public DBDT As DataTable

    'query parameters'
    Public parameters As New List(Of OleDbParameter)

    'query stats'
    Public recordcount As Integer

    Public Sub ExecuteQuery(Query As String)

        Dim ex As exception

        'reset query stats'
        recordcount = 0
        'rem REMOVE THIS LINE PERMANENTLY -     exception = ""

        'continue'
        Try
            'open connection'
            DBConnection.Open()

            'create database command'
            DBCommand = New OleDbCommand(Query, DBConnection)

            'load parameters into database command'
            parameters.ForEach(Sub(p) DBCommand.Parameters.Add(p))

            'clear parameter list'
            parameters.Clear()

            'execute command and fill datatable'
            DBDT = New DataTable
            DBDA = New OleDbDataAdapter(DBCommand)
            recordcount = DBDA.Fill(DBDT)

        Catch ex As Exception
            msgbox (ex.message)
        End Try

        'close connection to database'
        If DBConnection.State = ConnectionState.Open Then
            DBConnection.Close()
        End If

    End Sub

    Public Sub AddParameter(name As String, value As Object)
        'include query and command parameters'
        Dim newParameter As New OleDbParameter(name, value)
        parameters.Add(newParameter)
    End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: Thank you, changing the order of the parameters fixed my issue!

Comment: @Jamie - More than the order of the parameters was changed. Pay special attention to the **Try Catch Block**, The **Exception** and the **declaration of the exception**. These are core fundamentals. **Glad to be able to help, It was a team effort and everyone who commented helped too**.